# XlC flag qhalt issue

Tags: xlc

I'm using xlC 13.1.5 and CMake 3.5. When I try to compile an MPI package using CMake, I get the following error:

```
/opt/ibm/xlC/13.1.5/bin/.orig/xlc_r: warning: 1501-269 fpic is not supported on this Operating System platform.  Option fpic will be ignored.
error: 1540-5203 Unrecognized value "e" specified with option "halt".
1 error generated.
```

I read it is a bug of this compiler version, that adding qhalt flag with "e" option is not supported. Is there a workaround to solve the problem? At the moment I can't change compiler version.

Answer (score 1):

-qhalt=e is from an older compiler version, only -qhalt=w is supported on 13.1.5

When I try it I get a warning instead of an error

```
xlC -qhalt=w -c b1.cpp 
xlC -qhalt=e -c b1.cpp  
warning: 1540-5203 Unrecognized value "e" specified with option "halt".
1 warning generated.``
```

I'm assuming the option is in the makefile for your project which might be setup for the older xlC releases that accept the option.  Can you update it in the makefile?

-qhalt=w just get's transformed to -Werror and sent to clang on 13.1.5

Comment: Hi, that options is automatically added from the compiler, I don't know how. So I can't change this behaviour.

Comment: Check your makefiles, the option is not set by the compiler

Comment: Yes, you are right, that flag is added from my Makefile. Deleting that flags compilation works well. Thanks for the support.